# Problema al cargar datos en una tabla

Tags: c#, jquery, sql-server, asp.net, datatables

Tengo la siguiente página:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    <div class="row-fluid">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <h4 class="page-header">Productos</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
<div class="container-fluid"></div>
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h3 class="panel-title"><span class="fa fa-address-book-o"></span><b> Lista de Productos</b></h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          <p class="btnform btn btn-info btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#new" id="btnform" onclick="View();"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Nuevo Cliente</p><br><br>
          <div class="table-responsive">
              <table id="data-table-content" class="table table-hover table-condensed table-bordered">
                  <thead><tr><th>ID Producto</th><th>Nombre Producto</th><th>Categoria</th><th>HTS</th><th>Aduana</th><th>Precio</th><th>Opciones</th></tr></thead>
                  <tbody>
                      <asp:Literal ID="Literal1" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
                  </tbody>
              </table>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-footer">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Lo que hace es mostrar los datos de una consulta a la base de datos en una tabla, dentro del `tbody` tengo un `literal` que cargo con la siguiente llamada:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Literal1.Text = ObjProductsController.verTabla();
}
```

Este a su vez manda llamar un método, en donde cargo las filas de dicho `DataTable` de la siguiente manera:

```
public string verTabla()
{
    //Iniciar conexion con la BD Productos
    ProductsConnector ObjProductsConnector = new ProductsConnector(false);

    //Iniciamos la lista de Productos
    IList<ProductsDAO> resultList = new List<ProductsDAO>();

    string html = string.Empty;
        resultList = ObjProductsConnector.findAll();
        //Llenado de datos (tabla) con la lista que se recupero anteriormente
        foreach (ProductsDAO item in resultList)
        {
            string code = (item.idProducto).Trim();
            html += "<tr><td>" + code + "</td>";
            html += "<td>" + item.nombreProducto.Trim() + "</td>";
            html += "<td>" + item.categoria + "</td>";
            html += "<td>" + item.HTS + "</td>";
            html += "<td>" + code + "</td>";
            html += "<td>" + item.precio1 + "</td>";
            html += "<td><p class='text-success btn' id='btnupd' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#new' onclick='return Update(\"" + code + "\");'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit'> Modificar</span></p><br>";
            html += "<p class='text-danger btn' id='btndelete' onclick='return Delete(\"" + code + "\");'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'> Borrar</span></p></td></tr>";
        }
    ObjProductsConnector.SQLConnection.Close();
    return html;
}
```

El método anterior me manda a llamar lo que es otro método en donde tengo la consulta *SQL* de un `SELECT` el cual me trae aproximadamente 900 registros.

Mi problema radica que cuando cargo la página todo va muy bien, pero después de unos cuantos segundos la pagina se cuelga y no puedo seleccionar nada ni desplazarme ni nada, la página se congela totalmente. Quisiera ver si ustedes conocen alguna solución para ese problema. Ya que tengo otras dos `DataTable` y sí me funcionan bien pero solo con un registro, no sé si se deba a que son muchos registros o en donde radica el problema. Agradecería que me pudieran apoyar.

Me sale el siguiente error

Failed to load :26373/__browserLink/requestData/41acf70040fd4836bbde8ae3095a25d9 resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Pagínalo, ya que son muchos registros (según mi conocimiento a mas de 50 seria bueno que ya págines, para no saturar el servidor, haciendo llamadas a datos inecesarios), Aqui un tutorial de [paginado](https://geeks.ms/gperez/2009/03/02/paginando-eficientemente-en-asp-net/) usando ASP.NET, también podrías personalizarlo usando ajax y jquery, pero creo que no es tu caso. suerte.

Comment: Lo tomare en cuenta, aunque de casualidad no tendrás algún ejemplo utilizando ajax y jquery?

Answer (score 0):

Igual podrías mejorar el rendimiento cargando solo la tabla una única vez, al cargar la página:

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            Literal1.Text = ObjProductsController.verTabla();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Sigue igual, ya que si me carga bien los datos inclusive me muestra la tabla pero al momento de que el usuario la visualiza en cuestión de segundos se congela la pantalla y queda mucho tiempo cargando y después vuelve a responder

Comment: Prueba a utilizar un stringbuilder en lugar de un string normal. Cuando el texto es muy largo (en este caso toda la tabla) los stringbuilder mejoran la eficiencia en relación a concatenar en un string. https://dosideas.com/noticias/java/339-string-vs-stringbuffer-vs-stringbuilder

Puedes mirar también por ejemplo con Chrome y las opciones para desarrollador (F12) donde te esta consumiendo ese tiempo para ver que es lo que hace que se "bloquee".

Hice un pequeño ejemplo simplemente lanzando el código y en principio no debería de darte problemas:
 
https://dotnetfiddle.net/9cJneY

Comment: Probare el stringbuilder, para ver como me funciona. Te comento cuando miro las opciones de desarrollador me arroja el  siguiente error:
Failed to load :26373/__browserLink/requestData/41acf70040fd4836bbde8ae3095a25d9 resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Tu ejemplo me parece muy bien tu ejemplo y te comento que así lo estaba haciendo con MVC pero cambie a WebForms y con MVC no tenia ningun problema de hecho me traia mas de 1000 registros y todo iba bien, por eso es que se me hace muy raro que en el WebForm este teniendo fallas